# Requests is unable to get a pdf URL and download it

Tags: python, python-requests, shutil

For my job, we get a lot of product pdfs that we need to download. This leads to long lists of urls that I'd rather not click on over and over again. For some, I'm able to use the code below to download a pdf, but for others (like the one included) it seems like requests gets stuck in an endless loop of some sort when I ask it to get the url.

I've tried different parameters and different tips that I've seen elsewhere and nothing has worked. I'm new to code and to python so I'm probably missing something obvious here. Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import requests # to get image from the web
import shutil # to save it locally

url = "https://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/K-10411_spec_US-CA_Kohler_en.pdf"
filename = 'TEST-Image.pdf'

r = requests.get(url, stream = True)

if r.status_code == 200:

    r.raw.decode_content = True

with open(filename,'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    
    print('PDF sucessfully Downloaded: ',filename)
else:
    print('PDF Couldn\'t be retrieved')
```

Comment: Which OS are you on?  Have you tried a subprocess call with curl or wget?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. And no I haven't.

Comment: I think it's just that you forgot to assign your shutil call to a variable, and test if that returns an error.  I'm looking how they write it, but yea, otherwise, those'll do it.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 I have tried this out and it's actually hanging on the call to requests.get()

Comment: I've done some rudimentary testing, (placing print statements to see how far the program executes) and it seems to be getting stuck on the requests.get call. I can't get anything to happen after that point. I may need to assign a variable to that shutil call but I'm not sure that's the error I'm encountering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here, at least with the specific link provided, is that something on Kohler's side does not appreciate requests without a `user-agent` set in the headers. This is either a bug, or intentional. It may actually be an attempt to prevent people from doing exactly what you're doing - mass downloading their manuals. Regardless, the solution is simple.

Modify your requests call to look like this:

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, stream = True, headers = headers)
```

Note that the actual `user-agent` string provided is just the standard string for Chrome on Windows 10. You could probably use any `user-agent` string you wanted.

Comment: yea yea, I just noticed that.  They likely did it on purpose to avoid hot-linking.

Comment: That's actually really likely - I hadn't considered that.

Comment: That is very helpful! Thank you, and I'm grateful for your detailed explanation as well!